# What is an efficient way to erase substrings?

Tags: python, string, text

I have a long string and a list of `[end-index, string]` like the following:

```
long_sentence = "This is a long long long long sentence"
indices = [[6, "is"], [8, "is a"], [18, "long"], [23, "long"]]
```

An element `6, "is"` indicates that `6` is the end index of the word `"is"` in the string. I want to get the following string in the end:

```
>> print long_sentence
This .... long ......... long sentence"
```

I tried an approach like this:

```
temp = long_sentence
for i in indices:
    temp = temp[:int(i[0]) - len(i[1])] + '.'*(len(i[1])+1) + temp[i[0]+1:]
```

While this seems to be working, it is taking exceptionally long time (more than 6 hours on 5000 strings inside a 300 MB file). Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Side note: you do not need the `int()` part, as `i[0]` is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you do that `temp = temp...` assignment, Python has to create a new string (because Python strings are immutable).

What you might want to do instead is turn the string into a list of characters, then operate on the list of characters, and then join that list back together into a string again.

```
long_list = list(long_sentence)
for end, repstr in indices:
    long_list[end-len(repstr):end] = ['.'] * len(repstr)
new_sentence = ''.join(long_list)
```

Comment: Was just about to post this. You need the Python equivalent of a StringBuilder object.

Comment: @user978122 which is `''.join()`.

Comment: @user978122: what does a StringBuilder object do?

Comment: @EOL - It's a class that's used to accumulate string fragments and then produce the final string without creating smaller incomplete strings along the way. (Which is what `''.join()` also does.)

Comment: I would be most interested to know how fast this is, and whether it hits swap

Comment: @Will that would depend on the resources available on the system it's running on vs. the size of the dataset.

Comment: yes, I was thinking my box choke if you try to create a ~300,000,000 element list as specified in the question ... the answer: 2.3GB on my system; I trust everyone has 64bit OS these days?  I remain sceptical ;)

Comment: @Will: Thank you for the test.  I was afraid of that too.

Answer (score 3):

I would usually focus on writing the cleanest, readable concise code first and optimize second; and that's exactly the approach you've taken, bravo!  6 hours does seem untenable and time to optimize.  You have clearly separated the time to create the replacement string from the time taken to generate the list of indices in the first place?

[Benchmarking](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) shows **list comprehensions**, **joins** and **fake files** are fastest for string concatenation.  That was quite an old article - you may want to run the benchmark yourself to confirm the results - although it probably still holds.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the character substitution with the **mutable standard** `array` type:

```
>>> import array

>>> long_sentence = "This is a long long long long sentence"
>>> indices = [[6, "is"], [8, "is a"], [18, "long"], [23, "long"]]

>>> temp = array.array('c', long_sentence)  # Could replace long_sentence too
>>> for end, substr in indices:
...     temp[end-len(substr)+1:end+1] = array.array('c', '.'*len(substr))
...     
>>> temp
array('c', 'This .... long .... .... long sentence')
```

The new string can be written to an output file with:

```
temp.tofile(your_file)
```

(The string itself is returned by `temp.tostring()`.)

This approach has the advantage of **preventing too many new strings from being created through slicing**, which takes time. Another advantage is that it is **memory-efficient**: the string update is done in place (this is shown by the address found in `temp.buffer_info()`, which remains constant).  A side effect is that this memory-efficiency might allow your computer to **avoid swapping** and therefore speed things up even more.

You can also speed things up by **caching** the `'.'*len(substr)` strings through a special class `DotString` with a custom `__getitem__` method, where `DotString[4]` returns `'....'`, etc.

**PS**: Most optimization attempts benefit from **profiling** first.  You can profile your program with:

```
python -m cProfile -o stats.prof <Python program name and arguments>
```

You can then analyze the timings with:

```
python -m pstats stats.prof
```

The first command that you would typically run are `sort time` (sorting of the functions by time spent strictly inside the function code) and then `stats 10` (first 10 longest function executions).

You would do this on a truncated version of your input file, so that the run time is not too long.  This will tell you which functions take the most time and should be the focus of optimization.

**PPS**: The `'c'` type used in the example above is for byte strings (ASCII encoding, typically).  Character strings (aka unicode strings) can be handled with `'u'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid O(n) behavior by using sets for the membership testing and *str.join* to combine the results:

```
>>> redacts = set()
>>> indices = [[6, "is"], [8, "is a"], [18, "long"], [23, "long"]]
>>> for end, substr in indices:
        redacts.update(range(end-len(substr)+1, end+1))
>>> ''.join([('.' if i in redacts else c) for i, c in enumerate(long_sentence)])
'This .... long .... .... long sentence'
```

Alternatively, you can use a *bytearray* which lets you mutate the "string" in-place:

```
>>> arr = bytearray(long_sentence)
>>> for end, substr in indices:
        arr[end-len(substr)+1: end+1] = '.' * len(substr)
>>> str(arr)
'This .... long .... .... long sentence'
```

The latter technique only works for non-unicode strings.

Comment: This answer is interesting because it is quite creative. :)  While it looks quite fast, I would be curious about how fast it is compared to the `array` approach from my answer.